# partial index in django 1.6

Tags: python, django

I have the following model,

```
class Payment(AbstractBaseModel):

    sales_order = models.ForeignKey(
        'salesorders.SalesOrder',
        verbose_name=_('Sales Order'),
        unique=True)
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(
        'accounting.Invoice',
        help_text=_('invoice to which the payment belongs to'),
        verbose_name=_('invoice'),
        null=True,blank=True
    )
```

where both are unique together and index together,

So I rewrite my above model by adding `class Meta` option like this

```
class Payment(AbstractBaseModel):

    sales_order = models.ForeignKey(
        'salesorders.SalesOrder',
         verbose_name=_('Sales Order'),
         unique=True)
    invoice = models.ForeignKey(
        'accounting.Invoice',
        help_text=_('invoice to which the payment belongs to'),
        verbose_name=_('invoice'),
        null=True,blank=True
    )

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'payments'
        unique_together = ('sales_order','invoice')
        index_together = [['sales_order','invoice']]
```

which is not logical,because those field are actually **partial index** to each other,so as my django version is 1.6,what should i do in terms of such a situation?

Answer (score 1):

You really need to upgrade to a supported version of django - as there are [quite a few security updates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/security/) that you are missing.

In 1.7, partial indexes are supported through migrations - which itself was a feature absorbed from the South project.

You can (and should) use South - create an empty migration, and use [custom SQL](https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/databaseapi.html#db-execute) to create your partial index.

This is also the solution provided by django's built-in migrations, but they have a different wrapper around the commands; using `RunSQL`.